# Create a type which exhibits exact same behavior as STL container std::set

Tags: c++, c++11

I have following typedefs :

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> iprange;
typedef std::set<iprange> iprange_set;
```

When I try to write lexical_cast around `iprange` and `iprange_set` with some other types such as `Json::Value` or `std:string` compiler is giving error since a `typedef` is just an alias not a real type, so it can't be overloaded.

is there a way to have a type that exhibit the properties of existing type without typedef ?

The result I am looking for is that I should be able to declare variables using that type and also use it as parameter in `boost::lexical_cast`

Posting code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
using namespace std;

typedef set<string> ipaddr_list;

namespace boost {
    template<>
        string lexical_cast(const ipaddr_list* const & list)
        {
            return "qwe"; //actually code do convert ipaddr_list to string
        }
};

int main()
{
    ipaddr_list l;
    l.insert("45.5.5.5-56.6.6.6");

    string s = boost::lexical_cast<string>(l);
}
```

Compiler giving following error:

In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:349:13: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE'
            BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((result_t::value || boost::has_left_shift< std::basic_ostream< type >, T >::value),
            ^
and some more

Comment: I doubt the type aliases are the problem. Re-inventing the wheel is not a good approach. Please post a proper [mcve] so we could address [the actual root cause of your problem, rather than what you think is the solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You can use a typedef in a template argument so that's not your problem, show the code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting a type alias in `lexical_cast`; indeed, you do it every time you write `std::string`. You're misinterpreting something but, since you declined to demonstrate your problem, we can't tell you what that something is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provided a specialization for `lexical_cast(const ipaddr_list*)` - a function taking a pointer. But you are not calling that specialization - you are not in fact passing a pointer to `lexical_cast`. Instead, you are calling a general-purpose implementation, which tries to send `ipaddr_list` instance to a stream, but naturally fails to find a suitable overload of `operator<<`. This is what the assert is telling you.